# implementing a java interface and using generics

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have a java interface called BST (short for binary search tree) which has generic types Key,Value where Key extends Comparable.I defined it as below.

```
public interface BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>,Value> {

    public void put(Key key,Value value);

    public Value get(Key key);

    public void delete(Key key);

    public Iterable<Key> keys();

}
```

Now I want to define an implementation of the above interface.I tried this

```
public class BSTImpl<Key extends Comparable<Key> ,Value>  implements BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>,Value> {

... 

}
```

The above definition causes an error message in eclipse IDE ..The  `extends` token after `implements BST<Key` seems to be the culprit

> Syntax error on token "extends", , expected

If I omit the "extends" token from the definition (as given below),the error goes away, and I can get eclipse to generate the unimplemented methods correctly

```
public class BSTImpl<Key extends Comparable<Key> ,Value>  implements BST<Key ,Value> {
    @Override
    public void put(Key key, Value value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
    @Override
    public Value get(Key key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void delete(Key key) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
    }
    @Override
    public Iterable<Key> keys() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why does the extends token cause an error in the first place? can someone please explain?

Comment: You don't need to repeat that "Key extends whatnot" every time. You do that only when you introduce a type variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because

```
public class BSTImpl<Key extends Comparable<Key> ,Value>  implements BST<Key extends Comparable<Key>,Value> {
                    ^ type declaration                                   ^ type argument
```

In your class declaration, the generic type is a type declaration, something you can reuse later in the class body. In the interface you are implementing, it is a type argument argument. In other words, you are saying my class implements this interface with this type. you have to give it a specific type. It doesn't make sense to say `Key extends Comparable...` as a type argument.

The [Java Language Spec has more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2)

> The type parameter section follows the class name and is delimited by
>   angle brackets.

and in [the section for Superclasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)

> If the TypeDeclSpecifier is followed by any type arguments, it must be
>   a correct invocation of the type declaration denoted by
>   TypeDeclSpecifier, and none of the type arguments may be wildcard type
>   arguments, or a compile-time error occurs.

Comment: It's a shame use and declaration confusingly share syntax.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline Mind you they do so in C# as well, and arguably in C++ (the angle brackets go elsewhere). In fact it's pretty common for related language features to have the same syntax. C# however resolves this problem neatly by putting the **constraints** outside the angle brackets, without having to use a different syntax for use and declaration.

Comment: @millimoose It's a philosophy that goes back to at least C. Pre-ANSI types didn't appear next to parameters in function declarations - that came later having a repeat of parameter names (a mistake copied and made worse with C++/C With Classes constructors). Shame really as use and declaration have different needs, and could do without the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but I just wanted to add the *fix*.

Basically, you pass the type parameters onto the superclass/interface, like this:

```
public class BSTImpl<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> implements BST<Key, Value> {
    ... 
}
```

Also please adhere to java naming standards and use single letters for your generic parameter babes. Using words is too easily confused with being a class name.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords `extends` and `super` define *constraints* on generic types. It only makes sense to constrain type parameters coming **in**, not type parameters going **out**.

The situation is analogous to method parameters. When declaring a method, you use:

```
public void foo(Bar bar) { 
    //          ^ the type is a constraint on bar 
}
```

(The "constraint" is that any value passed to `bar` must be `Bar` or one of its subtypes.)

However, you call the method with just:

```
foo(someBar);
//  ^ no constraint specified here
```

That is, it doesn't make sense to constrain the type of a variable where it's used. (That was already done in the declaration.)

In your class declaration it's more confusing because a generic type is both declared and another one is used on the same line. The interpretation of that line is:

```
class BSTImpl<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
//                ^ a constraint on the types that can be passed to Key
    implements BST<Key, Value>
//                 ^ here we're passing Key to another generic type
```

Of course, just like with variables, the incoming "type" for `Key` has to be compatible with the types required where it's used, which is why you have to duplicate the constraints in the *declaration* of `BSTImpl`.

(This symmetry also illustrates what generics really are: they're higher-order type constraints, that is a way to specify "types of types".)